# How to delete a video from Gallery?

Tags: java, android, gallery

I've tried to delete my videos with this code, but on some devices they appear as damaged videos that can't be played in Gallery.

```
File videoFile = new File(filepath);
videoFile.delete();
```

How can I delete them properly?

Answer (score 2):

Gallery is displaying mediastore data.  To completely delete the file from the gallery you have to delete the mediastore database row for the video.

- In code remove the record from the mediastore.

  ```
  // delete the mediastore entry;
  getContext().getContentResolver().delete(mediaStoreUri, null, null);
  ```

Now all you need is the mediaStoreUri you can get it from the file path.

```
//found this on github
```

https://gist.github.com/jdeloach/3172742

Problem with above link I would prefer they use the ContentUris.withAppendedId static method to get the Uri but instead they just add a slash and string it out

```
Uri mediaStoreUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                            ImageId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on danny117's answer I found the solution for deleting videos in gallery:

```
/**
* Returns the Uri which can be used to delete/work with images in the photo gallery.
* @param filePath Path to IMAGE on SD card
* @return Uri in the format of... content://media/external/images/media/[NUMBER]
*/
private Uri getUriFromPath(String filePath) {
    long videoId;
    Uri videoUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri("external");

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Video.Media._ID};
    // TODO This will break if we have no matching item in the MediaStore.
   Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(videoUri, projection, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA + " LIKE ?", new String[] { filePath }, null);
   cursor.moveToFirst();

   int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(projection[0]);
   videoId = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);

   cursor.close();
   return contentUris.withAppendedId(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, videoUri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Java code seems right, have you declared the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in your manifest?
If not, add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` outside your `<application>` tag

Comment: The file is actually deleted, so I have already set the permission in manifest file.